# How to stop mysqli duplicate on random select

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query that select posts randomly created by users with views greater than 1 and not older than 2 weeks which works fine but I noticed that 1 or 2 or more posts have duplicates.
I tried to GROUP BY id but still get the same problem. Below is the query;

```
// the two variables work together with a Jquery load more am using to add 15 more posts on page scroll
$start = 0;
$limit = 15;

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE views > 1 AND date_created >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($database, $query);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // echo posts
}
```

How do I make the query randomly fetch all posts without duplicating any (which is caused by `ORDER BY RAND()`)

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() doesn't create any duplicates.

Comment: I have a jquery load more script that loads a new column on page scroll and when ever it loads, a post or more duplicate it self

Comment: I used just the PHP code to know if the Jquery code is responsible but I still get duplicates

Comment: well, on the consequent pages it could show duplicates. see the linked post for the solutions